# Trace_explorer clustering

Tags: r, trace

Can anyone explain me how traces are clustred in trace_explorer function of BupaR package?

Below is the trace explorer result of :

*sepsis %>%
    trace_explorer()*

Please help, thanks.

[image: trace_explorer]

Answer (score 2):

The grouping is by the frequency of that particular trace of activities (the numbers offered in the chart in the gray section).

If several traces get exactly the same (or very close) frequency, then they will be grouped together.

BTW, for this example, the total number of possible traces is 836; what you see in this chart is only what constitutes roughly 20% of the most frequent traces (as the default parameter is `coverage = 0.2`).

You can change that to a different value: for instance you can choose `coverage = 0.1` and you will see far less traces. Also you can see the "infrequent" traces first, by choosing the other parameter: `type = c("frequent", "infrequent")` in your call to the function `trace_explorer`.

For further control over what to see, you can use `trace_list()` function, which gives you the list of traces, and leaves you in charge of what to show or not to show.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. :)